# Java: Thinking in Java 4th edition. Why would one use a hexadecimal here?

Tags: java, binary, hex, bit-shift, parseint

"Start with a number that has a binary one in the most significant position (hint: Use a hexadecimal constant). Using the signed right-shift operator, right shift it all the way through all of its binary positions, each time displaying the result using Integer.toBinaryString( )."

"hint:use a hexadecimal constant", why is that? Isn't possible and simply easier to just declare the constant like this: `int i = Integer.parseInt("10101010", 2);` ?

Comment: Binary 10101010 is 0x000000AA. The binary digit in the left-most (most significant) position is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't *have* to use a hexadecimal constant, as you figured out. It's just nice because it's short, and you don't need to call any methods to use it. In addition, you get some compile-time checks that would guarantee that what you have is *actually* an `int`.

So in your case, you want a number with a binary one in the most significant position. For an `int`, that's this in binary:

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

So let's explore some ways of writing this in code. You can do what you suggested:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("10000000000000000000000000000000", 2);
```

But there are some issues with this:

1. Not very readable
2. You don't get compile-time checks to make sure what you *really* have is an `int`

So if you did this by accident:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("100000000000000000000000000000000", 2); // See the mistake?
```

You get this at runtime:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100000000000000000000000000000000"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
at Test.main(Test.java:3)
```

And that's no fun. Accidentally providing a number that is out of range (e.g. by adding another `0` by accident) results in a *runtime* exception. Doesn't make debugging too fun, does it...

---

Compile-time constants are much more preferable. If you have Java 7 or above, you can do this:

```
int i = 0b1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;
```

While still awkward, it's *significantly* more readable, and you at least get a compile-time error if you add one zero too many.

Hex is even better:

```
int i = 0x8000_0000;
```

So while it isn't *required*, it's probably *recommended*. You can expect that any programmers reading your code would understand hex, and it's short, readable, and you have the compiler catching some mistakes.

---

So to wrap up: Yes, it's *possible* to use your suggested syntax, but I wouldn't say it's easier. Hex is short, more readable, and you have less of a chance of leaving a mistake in your code. If you want to be *really* explicit, I'd still recommend using the binary literal over the `parseInt()` method, as it is safer.

---

(By the way, the example in your question isn't what you were asked for, but I'm assuming that was an example of syntax and not what you actually had)